# Centering a div in the content Ionic

Tags: css, angular, ionic3

I need to center 2 inputs with a toggle button below. Here is my code:

```
<ion-content class="body">

  <div class="inputs">
    <ion-input placeholder="Name" [(ngModel)]="name"></ion-input>
    <ion-input placeholder="Surname" [(ngModel)]="surname"></ion-input>
  </div>

  <div class="center">
    <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="male"></ion-toggle>
  </div>

</ion-content>
```

My css classes are these:

```
.body {

    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: color($colors, mybackground); 
}
.inputs {

    position: absolute;
    top: 33%;
    width: 100%;
    color: whitesmoke;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
}
```

Now I want some class to center orizontally the toggle. I tried all I could but I can't even center that thing. Moreover I'd like to have all in a unique div and I want to center this div vertically and orizontally. I've got only those components on this page. Is there any way?

Comment: use flexbox; `.selector { display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center }`

Comment: or @angular/flex-layout module with `fxLayoutAlign="center center"`

Comment: Could you write me a sample css classes and where I apply those classes?